# How to create directories in google drive using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I want to create directories using python script. I spent the whole day finding a tutorial about this but all the posts were old. I visited the Google Drive website but there was a short piece of code. When I used it like this,

```
def createFolder(name):
    file_metadata = {
    'name': name,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        fields='id').execute()
    print ('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

It gave me the following **error**

```
NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined
```

I didn't import anything I don't know which library to import? I just use this code. How to use this or updated code to create folders in google drive? I am a beginner.

Comment: " I visited the Google Drive website but there was a short piece of code." Could you link us to what you found?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# `client_secrets.json` should be your credentials file, as generated by Google.
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secrets.json', scope)
http = httplib2.Http()

drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=credentials.authorize(http))

def createFolder(name):
    file_metadata = {
        'name': name,
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        fields='id').execute()
    print('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))

createFolder('folder_name')
```

You will need to install `oath2client`, `google-api-python-client` and `httplib2` via pip.

To check, all of the folders:

```
page_token = None

while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                                          spaces='drive',
                                          fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                          pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

By the way:

> The user cannot directly access data in the hidden app folders, only
> the app can access them. This is designed for configuration or other
> hidden data that the user should not directly manipulate. (The user
> can choose to delete the data to free up the space used by it.)
>
> The only way the user can get access to it is via some functionality
> exposed by the specific app.
>
> According to documentation
> https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata you can access,
> download and manipulate the files if you want to. Just not though the
> normal Google Drive UI.

Comment: After installing the packages, I ran the code and it gave me this error. `ValueError: ('Unexpected credentials type', None, 'Expected', 'service_account')` Although the credentials is in the same path.

Comment: I searched online to find the solution and I found to make the service account in the Google platform and then use that credentials file. I used it and it worked by printing the id of the `folder_name` but it didn't create the `folder_name` in google drive.

Comment: If it is created then how to make it visible?

Comment: I want to find the `folder_name` in google drive but it not there.

Comment: I just want to create a folder in google drive.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uI220BJ0yXc In this video, a person created a folder in google drive it showed up in google drive.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

I recommend you to follow this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) to start working with the Drive API and Python. Once you have managed to run the sample, replace the lines above `# Call the Drive v3 API` with this [code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#create_a_folder) that a folder in your Drive. Furthermore, you have to modify the scopes in order to create a folder, in this case, you can use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`. The final result looks like this:

### Code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    folder_name = 'folder A'
    file_metadata = {
        'name': folder_name,
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        fields='id').execute()
    print('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### References:

- [Drive API: Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)
- [Drive API: Create a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#create_a_folder)

Comment: @fullfine you're doing same

Comment: What error are you getting? I forgot to change the scopes in the code, now it's updated. Delete the `token.json` and try again.

Comment: @fullfine `raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.', '{\n  "error": "deleted_client",\n  "error_description": "The OAuth client was deleted."\n}')
[Finished in 1.3s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-u', '/home/bilal/Documents/Projects/Data_monitoring_project/Python_files/Google.py']]
[dir: /home/bilal/Documents/Projects/Data_monitoring_project/Python_files]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games]`

Comment: It seems that something happened with the OAuth client on the [console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Try deleting the credentials.json and create a new one following the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python#step_1_turn_on_the). It is in the first step.

Comment: What type of credentials should be? Desktop app, web browser, web server. I don't which one to select.

Comment: It depends on your scenario, but `Desktop app` should work.